# Using Lodash to create a new object to contain objects in an array with similar property

Tags: javascript, data-structures, lodash

Is it possible to use Lodash to identify the common values of an array of objects' property and group them together into an object of arrays with the value being set by the common value identified?

Below is an example of a JSON data and Expected outcome.

Because in the future I would like to do something like calculating the total value or the highest value of `FavouriteNo`

Take note: This is a fake JSON data that I created.

The given JSON data

```
const arrayOfObj = [
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 91,
    FavouriteFood: "Pizza"
  },
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 5,
    FavouriteFood: "Hotdog"
  },
  {
    Name: "Sally-Tan",
    FavouriteNo: 124,
    FavouriteFood: "Ramen"
  },
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 1,
    FavouriteFood: "Burger"
  },
  {
    Name: "Ash-Charles",
    FavouriteNo: 825,
    FavouriteFood: "Donuts"
  },
  {
    Name: "Sally-Tan",
    FavouriteNo: 129,
    FavouriteFood: "Bread"
  }
];
```

The expected Arrangement

```
const expectedArrangement = {
      Code: [
        {
          Name: "John-Code",
          FavouriteNo: 91,
          FavouriteFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          Name: "John-Code",
          FavouriteNo: 5,
          FavouriteFood: "Hotdog"
        },
        {
          Name: "John-Code",
          FavouriteNo: 1,
          FavouriteFood: "Burger"
        }
      ],
      Tan: [
        {
          Name: "Sally-Tan",
          FavouriteNo: 129,
          FavouriteFood: "Bread"
        },
        {
          Name: "Sally-Tan",
          FavouriteNo: 124,
          FavouriteFood: "Ramen"
        }
      ],
      Charles: [
        {
          Name: "Ash-Charles",
          FavouriteNo: 825,
          FavouriteFood: "Donuts"
        }
      ]
    };
```

EDIT: I am planning to use Regex to detect the characters for the `Name` property

Comment: Why not just vanilla js?

Comment: Vanilla js solutions are welcome too. I am just wondering if lodash has a powerful function for these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_.groupBy accept function/string as a second parameter, in case of function it will compare that and group result with the same value (in this case, lastname).

This is another way to archive same goal, but hopefully easier to read & understand.

```js
const arrayOfObj = [
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 91,
    FavouriteFood: "Pizza"
  },
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 5,
    FavouriteFood: "Hotdog"
  },
  {
    Name: "Sally-Tan",
    FavouriteNo: 124,
    FavouriteFood: "Ramen"
  },
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 1,
    FavouriteFood: "Burger"
  },
  {
    Name: "Ash-Charles",
    FavouriteNo: 825,
    FavouriteFood: "Donuts"
  },
  {
    Name: "Sally-Tan",
    FavouriteNo: 129,
    FavouriteFood: "Bread"
  }
];

const result =_.groupBy(arrayOfObj, member => {
  const [firstname, lastname] = _.split(member.Name, '-');
  return lastname;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
const arrayOfObj = [
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 91,
    FavouriteFood: "Pizza"
  },
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 5,
    FavouriteFood: "Hotdog"
  },
  {
    Name: "Sally-Tan",
    FavouriteNo: 124,
    FavouriteFood: "Ramen"
  },
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 1,
    FavouriteFood: "Burger"
  },
  {
    Name: "Ash-Charles",
    FavouriteNo: 825,
    FavouriteFood: "Donuts"
  },
  {
    Name: "Sally-Tan",
    FavouriteNo: 129,
    FavouriteFood: "Bread"
  }
]

const result = arrayOfObj.reduce((acc, val)=>{
  const key =val.Name.split("-").pop()
  acc[key] = acc[key] ? acc[key].concat(val) : [val]
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Oh dear! Thank you so much! I am trying to understand how the solution works now.

Comment: Sorry, I am still trying to learn Javascript. I am wondering how did you set the name of the object?

Comment: split the string `John-Code` on `-` that gives `[John, Code]` then use `pop` on array that gives last element of array i.e. `Code`.

Comment: Hmm, so `acc` which I guess is the accumulator will create an object?

Comment: Thanks! I got 1 final question. If I would like to wrap this in an array. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using vanilla js.

The function `reduce` helps you to group the objects by the desired key.

```js
const arrayOfObj = [  {    Name: "John-Code",    FavouriteNo: 91,    FavouriteFood: "Pizza"  },  {    Name: "John-Code",    FavouriteNo: 5,    FavouriteFood: "Hotdog"  },  {    Name: "Sally-Tan",    FavouriteNo: 124,    FavouriteFood: "Ramen"  },  {    Name: "John-Code",    FavouriteNo: 1,    FavouriteFood: "Burger"  },  {    Name: "Ash-Charles",    FavouriteNo: 825,    FavouriteFood: "Donuts"  },  {    Name: "Sally-Tan",    FavouriteNo: 129,    FavouriteFood: "Bread"  }];;

var result = arrayOfObj.reduce((a, c) => {
  // Gets the desired key/name: i.e "John-Code" -> "Code"
  let [_, key] = c.Name.split('-'); 
   /** +--- Checkes if the key/name already exists, if so pushes the current object, 
    *  |    otherwhise initializes with an empty array and then pushes the current object.
    *  |
    *  |    'a[key] = []' adds a new key/name to the object with a specific value.
    *  |    i.e: a['Code'] = [] === { Code: [] }
    *  v
    */
  (a[key] || (a[key] = [])).push(c);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I am still trying to learn Javascript. I am wondering how did you set the name of the object?

Comment: @top22 great!! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash _.groupBy. Group By takes two parameters: the array and a key mapping function. The key function below written without arrow functions

```
function (itemInArray) {
    return itemInArray.Name.match(/-(.+)/)[1];
}
```

It is very similar to an [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). So the function maps the keys. Then groups the array by those mapped keys.

```
_.groupBy(arrayOfObj, i => i.Name.match(/-(.+)/)[1])
```

```js
const arrayOfObj = [
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 91,
    FavouriteFood: "Pizza"
  },
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 5,
    FavouriteFood: "Hotdog"
  },
  {
    Name: "Sally-Tan",
    FavouriteNo: 124,
    FavouriteFood: "Ramen"
  },
  {
    Name: "John-Code",
    FavouriteNo: 1,
    FavouriteFood: "Burger"
  },
  {
    Name: "Ash-Charles",
    FavouriteNo: 825,
    FavouriteFood: "Donuts"
  },
  {
    Name: "Sally-Tan",
    FavouriteNo: 129,
    FavouriteFood: "Bread"
  }
];

console.log(_.groupBy(arrayOfObj, i => i.Name.match(/-(.+)/)[1]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I did chance upon `_.groupBy` but the docs is confusing especially the [second example](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy). If you don't mind, could you share how it works?